# how to use multiple arguments in kdb where query?

Tags: kdb

I want to select max elements from a table within next 5, 10, 30 minutes etc.
I suspect this is not possible with multiple elements in the where clause.
Using both normal `<` and `</:` is failing. My code/ query below:

```
`select max price from dat where time</: (09:05:00; 09:10:00; 09:30:00)`
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong here?
The idea is to get the max price for each row within next 5, 10, 30... minutes of the time in that row and not just 3 max prices in the entire table.

```
select max price from dat where time</: time+\:(5 10 30)
```

This won't work but should give the general idea.

To further clarify, i want to calculate the max price in 5, 10, 30 minute intervals from time[i] of each row of the table. So for each table row max price within x+5, x+10, x+30 minutes where x is the time entry in that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but takes a lot of time. For 20k records, ~20 seconds, too much!. Any way to make it faster

```
 dat: update tmlst: time+\:mtf*60 from dat;
 dat[`pxs]: {[x;y] {[x; ts] raze flip raze {[x;y] select min price from x where time<y}[x] each ts }[x; y`tmlst]} [dat] each dat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
select c1:max price[where time <09:05:00],c2:max price[where time <09:10:00],c3:max price from dat where time< 09:30:00
```

You can paramatize this query however you like. So if you have a list of times, l:09:05:00 09:10:00 09:15:00 09:20:00 ... You can create a function using a functional form of the query above to work for different lengths of l, something like:

```
q)f:{[t]?[dat;enlist (<;`time;max t);0b;(`$"c",/:string til count t)!flip (max;flip (`price;flip (where;((<),/:`time,/:t))))]}
q)f l
```

You can extend f to take different functions instead of max, work for different tables etc.

Comment: thats precisely what i am trying to avoid. if i have to do for 5, 10, 20, 25, 30, 35....so on, this solution is not ideal

Comment: what's the usage of f? tried f[(15 30 60 120)], it just gives 4 values in seperate columns, not what i am looking for.

Comment: i realized the original scope of the question is answered with your approach. have edited to extend the scope of the question

Answer (score 0):

this constructs a step dictionary to map the times to your buckets:

```
q)-1_select max price by(`s#{((neg w),x)!x,w:(type x)$0W}09:05:00 09:10:00 09:30:00)time from dat
```

you may also be able to <strike>ab</strike>use [wj](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/wj):

```
q)wj[{(prev x;x)}09:05:00 09:10:00 09:30:00;`time;([]time:09:05:00 09:10:00 09:30:00);(delete sym from dat;(max;`price))]
```

if all your buckets are the same size, it's much easier:

```
q)select max price by 300 xbar time from dat where time<09:30:00 / 300-second (5-min) buckets
```

Comment: Again, the answer only returns constant buckets till 0930. I want to do this for all rows in the table. For each time x, I want to calculate the max price after x+5, x+15, x+30... minutes.